# How to calculate $\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right) \setminus B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From set theory I know that:

$$X \setminus\bigcup_i A_i = \bigcap_i X\setminus A_i$$
$$X \setminus\bigcap_i A_i = \bigcup_i X\setminus A_i$$

But How can We express, for $B \subseteq X$, and $A_i \subseteq X$:

$$\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right) \setminus B\ \ \  \text{and}\ \ \ \left(\bigcap_i A_i\right) \setminus B \ \ \ \ \text{?}$$

Is it true that: $\left(\bigcup_i A_i\right) \setminus B = \left(\bigcup_i A_i \setminus B\right) ? $

Comment: Yes, it is true: $x\in\left(\bigcup_iA_i\right)\setminus B$ iff $x\notin B$ **and** there is an $i$ such $x\in A_i$, i.e., iff $x\in A_i\setminus B$ for some $i$, and **that** is true iff $x\in\bigcup_i(A_i\setminus B)$.

Comment: $\left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right)\setminus B=\left(\bigcup_{i}A_i\right)\cap B^c=\bigcup_{i}\left(A_i\cap B^c\right)=\bigcup_{i}\left(A_i\setminus B\right)$. Of course Brian M. Scott's answer is better because it uses only definitions.

Comment: Reason is that $B$ does not depend on index $i$.